# can I forge the URL on domain forwarding

Tags: .htaccess, cross-domain

I have the domain "mydomain.org" which is forwarded to http://mysite.at/site. My goal is to keep "mydomain.org" in the adress-bar of the browser.

If I use the so called "stealth mode" from the domain-forwarding company (in this case the "mydomain.org" stays in the adress-bar), they generate a frameset pointing to my website. But unfortunatly they insert the following meta-tag () in the frameset which breaks my design in IE. And they are not willing to change this (I talked to them).
I found out that "IE=EmulateIE7" is set for all the (frame)children, and it cannot be overruled within the children. Also it is not possible to change the parent from within a child (I think because of security reasons).

So my question: can I forge the adress-bar of the browser to "mydomain.org" (aktually it is "mysite.at/site") when not using a frameset?

On "mysite.at/site" a Joomla 2.5 is running. Therefore I have access to all php-files and to .htaccess.

Thanks for your help,
Michael